# Power BI - calculated returned distinct count

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop, calculated-columns

I am relatively new to Power BI and still learning how to put together some more complex measures. I have a need to determine the values in field 1 where specific text occurs in field 12. The measure should then count the number of distinct entries in field 22 that occur at each occurrence of the determined values in field 1. For example, the specific text occurs in field 12 at rows 12, 30, 47, and 53. The corresponding values in field 1 are V53H94I6, Q30L68H5, E51H94U2, O18Q60R2, and P31L47Y4 respectively. Within field 1, V53H94I6 occurs at row 12, Q30L68H5 occurs at row 23, E51H94U2 occurs at rows 30 to 32, O18Q60R2 occurs at rows 47 to 48, and P31L47Y4 occurs at rows 52 to 53. I need the measure to count the number of distinct entries in field 22 for rows 12, 23, 30, 31, 32, 47, 48, 52, and 53.

As I have not created a measure this complex yet, I am using ChatGPT to help me put things together. Unfortunately, Power BI shows the following error "A function 'CONTAINS' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed." Any help with adjusting the code to result in the desired count would be greatly appreciated!

```
DistinctField22Count =
VAR RelevantEvents =
    CALCULATETABLE(
        VALUES('YourTableName'[Field 1]),
        CONTAINS('YourTableName', 'YourTableName'[Field 12], "Specific Text")
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT('YourTableName'[Field 22]),
        'YourTableName'[Field 1] IN RelevantEvents
    )
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.